# Lifefay freemarker ADT: methods unavailable?

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, freemarker

I'm trying to work on some ADT for asset publisher (Documents and Media type), but I often have a message telling me that :

```
Expression assetRenderer.getDataRepositoryId is undefined
```

or

```
Expression assetRenderer.getFileEntryId is undefined
```

I found some threads where people said that we must add

```
velocity.engine.restricted.classes=
velocity.engine.restricted.variables=
freemarker.engine.restricted.classes=
freemarker.engine.restricted.variables=
```

in `portal-ext.properties` to get some more classes and variables available, but still I'm not able to call some methods and i don't know why.

I did a

```
${assetRenderer.getClassName()}
```

which returns: `com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.model.DLFileEntry`

So I should be able to use any DLFileEntry class public methods (and extended classes), right?

What do I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asset renderer renders asset entries of the given class (ei. `JournalArticle` or `DLFileEntry` in your case). Asset renderer itself is not instance of the given class (in Java sense). It is always instance of `com.liferay.portlet.asset.model.AssetRenderer`.

To get instance of the related `DLFileEntry`, you must use `DLFileEntryLocalService` to find it.

```
<#-- Obtains instance of DLFileEntryLocalService -->
<#assign DLFileEntryLocalService = serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLFileEntryLocalService") />

<#-- Function returning underlying DLFileEntry for the given AssetEntry -->
<#function getDLFileEntry assetEntry>
    <#return DLFileEntryLocalService.getDLFileEntry(assetEntry.getClassPK())/>
</#function>
```

Please note, that you need to enable the usage of `serviceLocator` explicitly by setting `freemarker.engine.restricted.variables=` in `portal-ext.properties`.